# fraction with 2 variables, and radicals in numerator

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I arrived at the following solution to a problem in pre-calculus:

$$
\frac{2xh + h^2 + \sqrt{x+h} - \sqrt{x}}{h}
$$

However, this can be simplified further to:

$$
2x+h+\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt{x}}
$$

The steps to simplify were not provided. I substituted in $x = 9, h = 16$ to confirm and I've searched a few places, but am at a loss as to how the term

$$
\frac{\sqrt{x+h} - \sqrt{x}}{h}
$$

can be simplified to:

$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt{x}}
$$

What are the steps and relevant rules?

Comment: difference of two squares

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of the very useful "[multiply by the conjugate](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/conjugate.html)" trick. The trick is based on the fact that
$$(a+b)(a-b)=a^2-b^2,$$
which is easy to verify by direct multiplication — but it's so useful that it's worth remembering!

In your example, the conjugate of the numerator $\left(\sqrt{x+h}-\sqrt{x}\right)$ is the expression $\left(\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt{x}\right)$, so we're going to multiply the numerator and denominator simultaneously by this conjugate:
$$\frac{\sqrt{x+h}-\sqrt{x}}{h}=\frac{\left(\sqrt{x+h}-\sqrt{x}\right)\left(\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt{x}\right)}{h\left(\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt{x}\right)}=\frac{\left(\sqrt{x+h}\right)^2-\left(\sqrt{x}\right)^2}{h\left(\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt{x}\right)}=\frac{x+h-x}{h\left(\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt{x}\right)}=\frac{h}{h\left(\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt{x}\right)}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt{x}}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that
$$h = x+h-x = (\sqrt{x+h}-\sqrt{x})(\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt{x})$$

and therefore,
$$\frac{h}{\sqrt{x+h}+\sqrt{x}} =  \sqrt{x+h}-\sqrt{x}$$